# How to keep moving circles inside the stage?

Tags: java, javafx, geometry

So ive got this code where im trying to get the moving circles to bounce on the walls so they dont go outside the stage. Ive tried to do it with the moveCircle method but i feel really out of my comfort zone.

```
import javafx.animation.Animation.Status;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.effect.Light;
import javafx.scene.effect.Lighting;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TimelineSample extends Application {

    Timeline timeline;

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        double height = primaryStage.getHeight();
        double width = primaryStage.getWidth();
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, width, height));
        double radius = 30;
        Circle circle = new Circle(radius, radius, radius, Color.BLUE);
        Circle circle2 = new Circle(radius, radius, radius, Color.RED);
        Light.Distant light = new Light.Distant();
        light.setAzimuth(-135.0);
        Label label = new Label(
                "Space för starta spelet\nSpace för att pausa spelet\nTryck på cirklarna för att byta färg på dem");
        Label label2 = new Label("44");
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
        label2.setStyle(("-fx-padding : 100;"));
        root.setBottom(label2);
        root.setCenter(label);
        Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary();
        Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();

        ScrollBar sbSpeed = new ScrollBar();
        sbSpeed.setMax(50);
        sbSpeed.setValue(25);
        sbSpeed.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);

        circle.opacityProperty().bind(sbSpeed.valueProperty().divide(30));
        circle2.opacityProperty().bind(sbSpeed.valueProperty().divide(30));
        sbSpeed.setOnScroll(e -> {
            circle.setTranslateX(+50);
        });

        circle.centerXProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().divide(2));
        circle.centerYProperty().bind(root.heightProperty().divide(2));
        circle.radiusProperty().bind(Bindings.min(root.widthProperty().divide(10),
                root.heightProperty().divide(10)));     

        circle2.centerXProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().divide(2));
        circle2.centerYProperty().bind(root.heightProperty().divide(2));
        circle2.radiusProperty().bind(Bindings.min(root.widthProperty().divide(10),
                root.heightProperty().divide(10)));     




        root.setTop(sbSpeed);

        primaryStage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth() * 0.40);
        primaryStage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight() * 0.40);

        Lighting lighting = new Lighting();
        lighting.setLight(light);
        lighting.setSurfaceScale(5.0);
        circle.setEffect(lighting);
        circle2.setEffect(lighting);
        timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll

        (new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(circle.translateXProperty(),
                0)),
                new KeyFrame(new Duration(5000), new KeyValue(circle
                        .translateXProperty(), width - (radius * 2))));

        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(
                        circle2.translateYProperty(), 0)),
                new KeyFrame(new Duration(5000), new KeyValue(circle2
                        .translateYProperty(), height - (radius * 2))));
        timeline.play();
        root.getChildren().addAll(circle, circle2);
        boolean a = true;
        root.requestFocus();

        root.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.SPACE)) {

                if (timeline.statusProperty().getValue().equals(Status.RUNNING)) {
                    timeline.pause();
                } else
                    timeline.play();
            }

        });

        circle.setOnMousePressed(event -> {

            if (circle.getFill().equals(Color.BLACK))

                circle.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
            else if (circle.getFill().equals(Color.BLUE))
                circle.setFill(Color.BROWN);
            else if (circle.getFill().equals(Color.YELLOW))
                circle.setFill(Color.BROWN);
            else if (circle.getFill().equals(Color.BROWN))
                circle.setFill(Color.BLACK);

            else
                circle.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        });

        circle2.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            if (circle2.getFill().equals(Color.BLACK))

                circle2.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
            else if (circle2.getFill().equals(Color.BLUE))
                circle2.setFill(Color.BROWN);
            else if (circle2.getFill().equals(Color.YELLOW))
                circle2.setFill(Color.BROWN);
            else if (circle2.getFill().equals(Color.BROWN))
                circle2.setFill(Color.BLACK);

            else
                circle2.setFill(Color.BLUE);
            // }

        });
    }

    protected void moveCircle(Circle circle) {

             if (circle.getCenterX() < circle.getRadius() || 
                     circle.getCenterX() > circle.getCenterY() - circle.getRadius()) {
                 circle.translateYProperty(); 
            }
            if (circle.getCenterY() < circle.getRadius() || 
                    circle.getCenterY() > circle.getCenterX() - circle.getRadius()) {
                circle.translateXProperty();} 
            }






    public void pause() {
        timeline.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

}
```

just need to start the balls and it will work.

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

Now this is general pseudo code for something like this, although not specific to your problem this is the general way of making this "bounce" off the edge of the screen.

First off you need 5 pieces of information, the circles velocity (on x and y, as variables or a vector2), the circles radius (or diameter), the circle position (on x and y, as variables or a vector2) and the screens width and height.

Also depending on if the origin point of the circle is the center (you will need radius), bottom left or top left (you will need diameter). In my example we assume the origin is bang on the middle of the circle.

The generally idea goes something like this:

```
int windowWidth = 800, windowHeight = 600;
Circle c;

// Check if the left or right side of the circle leaves the screen bounds
// if so, reverse the velocity (mirror it)
if(c.x - c.radius < 0 || c.x + c.radius > windowWidth)
    c.velocityX = -x.velocityX;

// Check if the top or bottom side of the circle leaves the screen bounds
// if so, reverse the velocity (mirror it)
if(c.y - c.radius < 0 || c.y + c.radius > windowHeight)
    c.velocityY = -c.velocityY;
```

Hope that makes sense, it is a case of checking if the circle is passed the screen boundaries and simply mirroring the velocity on that given axis. So if the ball is moving at a velocity of 5,0 (directly right) and then goes beyond the window width, we want to take the velocity on x and negate it, so now the velocity becomes -5, 0 (directly left).

The one issue with this is the linear look, you can easily add some other variables like acceleration, restitution, friction and drag to give it a more realistic feel.